# How to log rxjs observable and operator names?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'd like to replicate the observable dependency graph for time travel debugging, similar to this example (https://youtu.be/HQWnCo_lMJQ?t=74).

How can I access the names of the observables and piped operators?  Initial attempts have been so far unsuccessful.

e.g., in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/j7tvss-adrhxq?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts), tap can access the values, but I haven't found a way to log `map`, `take`, and `interval` at the same time.

```js
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
interval(100)
  .pipe(
    take(3),
    map((e, i) => i * 2),
    tap(console.log)
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: console.log,
    error: console.error,
    complete: () => console.log('complete')
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is to create new operators. For example, here is 'map'

```
function _map(project: (value: unknown, index: number) => number) {
  return function<T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return source.pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('map')),
      map(project)
    );
  };
}
```

Take a look at this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/j7tvss-gboupg?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

The result is you are using the `map` operator and you also insert a console log with the operator name.

You should check out this article to learn more about creating your own operators https://netbasal.com/creating-custom-operators-in-rxjs-32f052d69457

Comment: Thanks for the solid answer and examples Alex.  Good to know there's no builtin way.